# Can not start or uninstall Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, uninstallation

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 for Web on my Windows 7 client. During the installation, I lost my network connection. At the end, it seems the installation succeeds. But I found no entry in the start menu of windows.
So, I want to repair / uninstall Visual Studio.
I started the Uninstaller via System Control and I have the two buttons "Repair" and "Uninstall". In both scenarios, the question "Are you sure you want to cancel the setup?". If i click "No", the previous screen with the two buttons is displayed, if I click "Yes", the uninstaller closes....

**Edit:**
I also re-run the installer, but the same question, with the same results appear.

How can I uninstall Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

try to install visual studio 2013 it should ask uninstall/repair.

try it and see if its helps

Comment: i know it should be comment but but i am at low reputation so i cannot put commnent below question